# Buttonclick is not working VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can you help me with this, my code doesn't have error but when I click the button to go back to the previous group box it doesn't work :( Idk why can you help me guys figure it out?

The app has login form when you login it directs you to the another form that you can choose categories then if I select a category example I chose gadgets it redirects me to the gadgets groupbox then if I try to go back it doesn't go back in the categories page

The button2.click, button6.click and button3.click are the back buttons

Here's my code

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    GroupBox2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sbutton As DialogResult
    sbutton = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout now?", "Logging out", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If sbutton = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    GroupBox1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    GroupBox3.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel2_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel2.LinkClicked
    GroupBox4.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    MsgBox("Message was sent!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    GroupBox2.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    MsgBox("Message was sent!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    TextBox2.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    GroupBox2.Show()
    GroupBox3.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GroupBox2.Hide()
    GroupBox3.Hide()
    GroupBox4.Hide()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Is the handler invoked at all?  Is it the handler you expect?  Where does it fail?  We can't debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: When I choose one of my categories then if I click the "Back" button to go back in the categories it doesn't go back to the categories.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the "Back" button is?  You named your variables `Button1`, `Button2`, etc.  Also, "it doesn't work" isn't a meaningful description of the problem.  What *does* it do?  Use your debugger.

Comment: Sorry, I already edited it.

Comment: Perhaps it works, but the other GroupBoxes are overlapping those you're trying to show? Try calling `.Hide()` or `.Visible = False` on the other groupboxes before you show the new one when pressing one of the buttons.

Comment: I replaced them all with Visible and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Umm did you type this yourself or generate it from a UI? Shouldn't it be button_OnClick not button_click?